# Include point coordinates in a string with Google Earth Engine using JavaScript

Tags: coordinates, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, string, concatenation

I am making a time-series plot with data extracted from a point, and I would like to include the point coordinates in the title text.

e.g. 'Timeseries from point (61.08457, 6.03583)'

However, I can't see how to get the coordinates as a simple string object that can be concatenated neatly.

See the code below.

```
var centre_pt = (ee.Geometry.Point(6.10736, 61.49845));

var coordinates = (centre_pt.coordinates())
var lat = ee.Number(coordinates.get(1)).format('%.6f')
var long = ee.Number(coordinates.get(0)).format('%.6f')
var coordinates = (ee.String('(').cat(long).cat(', ').cat(lat).cat(')'));  

print(coordinates)

var title = ('Timeseries from point: ' + coordinates)
print(title)
```

When I print it, it comes up as:

```
Timeseries from point: ee.String({
  "type": "Invocation",
  "arguments": {
    "string1": {
      "type": "Invocation",
      "arguments": {
...etc
```

I don't want all the extra bits. How do I get just the coordinates to use in a concatenated string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the title variable. It needs to be treated as an `ee.String` and `cat()` with the coordinates.

```
var title = ee.String('Timeseries from point: ').cat(coordinates)
```

Also, the 'coordinates' variable is overwritten here. You can rename the first one or simply avoid it.

```
var lat = ee.Number(centre_pt.coordinates().get(1)).format('%.6f')
var long = ee.Number(centre_pt.coordinates().get(0)).format('%.6f')
var coordinates = (ee.String('(').cat(long).cat(', ').cat(lat).cat(')'));
```